# .gitignore to manage vimfiles under windows

Tags: git, vim, gitignore

- windows 7 running vim.
- want to use the same 
  `c:\users\xxxx\_vimrc` 
  `c:\users\xxxx\vimfiles\....` Across multiple windows 7 computers, e.g. work, home desktop, home laptop.
- For each of those windows 7 machines, each has its own home directory with different files say videos/photos/music/documents. I do NOT want to sync those files to be the same. Only the `_vimrc` and folders/files under `\vimfiles`
- The method I am contemplating is using git to manage ONLY `c:\users\xxxx\_vimrc` and `xxxx\vimfiles\....` as a repo and ignore all other files.
- I will arrange all files one 1st win7 home and then commit and push one repo into github, and clone it on multiple win 7 home folders. I understand I have to first clone from github into a local folder say `c:\temp\local_git_vim_repo`, and then manually copy contents within `c:\temp\local_git_vim_repo` to home folder so that all the correct git config information is copied over. I did NOT use any git submodules to manage one repo within another repo. The .git folder is copied over after clone.
- after this, I will simply add new files/push/fetch/merge on different win 7 home folders.
- Above is the plan. If you have better ways to achieve what I want to do, please advice.
- The execution of the plan failed at the first step when trying to push the 1st computer's `home_folder\_vimrc, vimfiles` into github. The files under `home_folder\vimfiles\bundle\` is empty.
- Since I do NOT want git to manage any files except for `_vimrc, vimfiles\...` under `home_folder`, I will have to gitignore most of the files except for those I want to manage according to the plan.
- my .gitignore looks like the following

`c:\users\xxxx\.gitignore`

`*
!_vimrc
!*/
!.gitignore
!vimfiles/**
!vimfiles/**/*.vim`

- after I did add/commit/push, vimfiles/bundle's sub folders are only empty folders on git-hub. 
  In other words I can NOT stage files such as

`vimfiles/bundle/tabular/plugin/Tabular.vim
vimfiles/bundle/tabular/doc/Tabular.txt
....`

- it only give me an empty folder unto
  `vimfiles/bundle/tabular`
  and there is nothing in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `.gitignore`, here, you only need to put your `vimrc` in `vimfiles`:

```
c:\users\xxxx\vimfiles\vimrc    <-- "vimrc", not "_vimrc"
```

The empty directories under `bundle` are probably due to you using git submodules. Please add more background to your question (and use markdown).